# Custom trigger in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which exports data to other spreadsheet, what is want to create custom trigger based on specific cell value (when ever we change the value in specific cell, it trigger the script. i don't need the on open/on edit, time specific or from submission,i really need is the trigger when ever value of specific cell changes

Comment: i want to specific cell reference to this trigger var ssKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

function myFunction() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
           .forSpreadsheet(ssKey)
           .onEdit()
           .create();
}

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it very well, but I think you'll need the [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) and check the ROW and COLUMN edited, like so:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getColumn() == 5 && e.range.getRow() == 2){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit').forSpreadsheet(ssKey).onEdit() .create();
  }
}
```

Or if it's a specific value:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getValue() == "This value"){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit').forSpreadsheet(ssKey).onEdit() .create();
  }
}
```

Comment: either `e.range.getColumn() == 10 && e.range.getRow() == 70` or `e.range.getA1Notation() == "J70"`.

Comment: it keeps giving the type-error (cannot read property "range" from undefined